# XCode Mach-O linker error

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, mach-o

After upgrading to XCode 4.5 GM from XCode 4.3 + llvm 3.1, I start getting the following linker errors.
I have verified that the static library where  "_InvokeBridge" is defined is linked correctly.

Any idea what might cause the error? Also, Are there tips to investigate Mach-o linker error in general?

```
undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "void     pplx::details::_UnrealizedChore::_InvokeBridge<pplx::details::_PPLTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, pplx::task<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const> >::_InitialTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, BI::ServicesDocumentSession::GetViewUriAsync()::$_3, pplx::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>, pplx::details::_UnrealizedChore> >(pplx::details::_PPLTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, pplx::task<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const> >::_InitialTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, BI::ServicesDocumentSession::GetViewUriAsync()::$_3, pplx::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>, pplx::details::_UnrealizedChore>*)", referenced from:
  pplx::details::_PPLTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, pplx::task<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const> >::_InitialTaskHandle<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const>, BI::ServicesDocumentSession::GetViewUriAsync()::$_3, pplx::details::_TypeSelectorNoAsync>, pplx::details::_UnrealizedChore>::_PPLTaskHandle(std::__1::shared_ptr<pplx::details::_Task_impl<std::__1::shared_ptr<BI::Url const> > > const&) in libDataPlatform.a(ServicesDocumentSession.o)
```

thank you much,
A

Comment: Pos this in the apple forums. Not here

Comment: I had a problem similar to this, and I couldn't fix it until I unmounted all my non-boot drives. It turned out Xcode was looking in some random place on some other hard drive for something, and finding it there, but it was the wrong version. So unmounting fixed it. Not sure if it's the same problem, but it looks very similar.

Comment: You can use `otool -L` and `otool -fahv` to see what libraries something is linked against, and the architectures contained in a library. It's possible that the library is defining the symbol only for a different architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Go to project target, Build settings, Then set **Architecture** to other,

delete the $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)  , then write **armv7**

let me know if this works or not, i had similar issues too.